# How to concatenate two of the values of a JSON-array in a certain order?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, concatenation, aggregate

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I have a table with JSON arrays, that contain JSON-objects in the following format:

```
[]
[{animal:cat}, {plant:sunflower}, {car:mercedes}]
[{animal:dog}]
[{animal:dog}, {car:audi}]
[]
```

I need to output a table that combines the values of *animal* and *plant*, and then calculates the amount of each key value combination. Null values need to be ignored, but situations where there is only either *animal* or *plant* are also grouped as their own group. *car* needs to be removed completely.

My ideal end-result resembles this:

```
Animal : Plant     |  Amount
---------------------------
cat : oak          |   54
cat : sunflower    |   127
dog                |   8
cow : oak          |   3
...
```

#### What I have attempted:

```sql
SELECT
    ((json_array_elements(Table.json_array)::JSONB
- 'car')::JSON#>>'{animal}')::TEXT AS elems,
    count(*)
FROM    Table
GROUP BY elems
```

I can see that this gives me *animal* as a string and counts each instance of it. I can also remove *car* by casting the JSON array into JSONB, then remove *car* with the minus operator, and cast back to JSON. Casting to JSONB changes the order of my values though.

But when I try to concatenate a string from *animal* and *plant*:

```sql
SELECT
    (((json_array_elements(Table.json_array))::JSON#>>'{animal}') || ' : ' || ((json_array_elements(Table.json_array))::JSON#>>'{plant}'))
    ::TEXT AS elems,
    count(*)
FROM    Table
GROUP BY elems
```

I receive the error message:

> functions and operators can take at most one set argument

Tried `json_agg`, `CONCAT()` and `||`, same result.

I have tried to figure out how to cast either the *animal* or *plant* side as something else than a set, but so far have failed to progress.

How to get the desired result? I am constrained to using only Postgres commands as I am working with the database through Apache superset, a data visualization program.

Comment: I'd rather change the way you store data, but based on the structure I think this should work - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ca2b41c54357253eda9d22182ad70c5b

Comment: Is your sample value supposed to represent a single field, or several column values? Please provide the relevant table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and valid sample values. And can there be more than one animal or plant in the same JSON array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT animal_plant, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT t.id, concat_ws(' : '
                        , string_agg(elem ->> 'animal', '|')
                        , string_agg(elem ->> 'plant' , '|')) AS animal_plant
   FROM   tbl t, json_array_elements(t.json_array) j(elem)
   GROUP  BY t.id
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This concatenates all cats and all dogs from the same JSON value, since you did not disclose whether there can be multiple. (If there is at most one each, it produces your desired result.)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a18f921ca0134994d6eee5892b4cc658)*

May get simpler with SQL/JSON in Postgres 12 ...
(You'll need to upgrade to a modern version of Postgres soon, anyway.)